# Is there a possible connection between a Microsoft Redistributable and a virus?

Tags: windows-8, virus, c++, redistributable

I have a question about Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables.  I understand in general that I - a complete amateur - should not remove them.  But - there are 7 all of which were installed when I bought the computer in Nov 2012 - with one exception.  That one exception was installed (installed itself) eleven months later and it was installed on the day and at the time when I unknowingly downloaded a virus-filled program.  Most of the program I got rid of but a pop-up window for SpeedAnalysis keeps reappearing,  Would it be safe to remove that one redistributable ("...2008 Redistributable - x86 9.021022)? Is it connected with the virus pop-up?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried scanning with [malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)? It's free for manual scans and it's the most efficient antimalware I've seen -- for that price that is.

Another free tool is spybot s&d: http://www.filehippo.com/download_spybot_search_destroy/

Also check if you have removed the SpeedAnalysis addon from your browser.

You have more options/malware scanners at malwaretips: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/speed-analysis-virus/

Answer (score -1):

They shouldn't be.

Every Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is digitally signed.  If it was altered, the system would let you know.  That said, it is possible for your system to be compromised in a way that causes it to bypass the digital signature check.  If your system is infected, though, it's unlikely to be the Redistributable itself, but another program.